# Is there a way to optimize tool panel?

Tags: add-on, panel, tools

I have too many addons so there are many tabs in the tool section.  I would like to organize those somehow

Comment: Maybe getting a larger monitor. Do you need all of them active at the same time?

Comment: I haven't used it, but this looks like exactly what you need! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4DwMwso9MR8

Comment: thanks!.........